# Telnet from inside a telnet session (Python)

Tags: python, telnetlib

I am trying to telnet to a remote device from another remote device, doing a nested telnet using telnetlib. While I can easily communicate with the first device, I am not able to get the output from the second device. Below is my code, am I doing this correctly?

```
import telnetlib

HOST = "firstDevice"
user = "lab"
password = "lab"

tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)

tn.read_until("Username: ")
tn.write(user + "\n")
if password:
    tn.read_until("Password: ")
    tn.write(password + "\n")

#Nested telnet
tn2 = telnetlib.Telnet("secondDevice") 
tn2.read_until("#")   
tn2.write("sh clock\n")

#Close tn2
tn2.write("exit\n")
print tn2.read_all()

#Close tn
tn.write("exit\n")
print tn.read_all()
```

**Edit 1**

```
import telnetlib

HOST = "firstDevice"
user = "lab"
password = "lab"

tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)

tn.read_until("Username: ")
tn.write(user + "\n")
if password:
    tn.read_until("Password: ")
    tn.write(password + "\n")

#Nested telnet
tn.write("telnet secondDevice\n") 
tn.write("sh clock\n")

#Close nested session
tn.write("exit\n")

#Close tn
tn.write("exit\n")
print tn.read_all()
```

Comment: Interesting. Have you manually executed to do the exact sequence of commands you are trying to automate here?

Comment: Also, your second version is missing `tn2.read_until("#")`

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing a nested connection in your code. You are just connecting to two different computers from localhost, but apparently you can not actually connect to the second one. To do a nested Telnet to the second host, you have to tell the first one to telnet to the second one: replace `tn2 = telnetlib.Telnet("secondDevice")` with

```
tn.write("telnet secondDevice\n")
```

Since you have a nested connection, all your localhost should see is `tn`. You can get rid of the `tn2` object entirely. All interaction with the second device will be done by sending strings to the first device, which is in a session connected to the second device.

Comment: Thanks! I tried this, followed by two exit strings, but the session becomes unresponsive and does not come out of the session when I write the telnet string. Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you processing login for the nested session correctly?

Comment: The nested session doesn't require login credentials. I have updated the code in the question according to the answer.

Comment: Just saw your edit. Don't forget to do `tn.read_until("#")`. You still need to wait for the prompt.